# Error while installing wxpropertygrid on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: installation, wxwidgets, configure

I am trying to install wxpropertygrid. I have successfully installed wxwidgets. I have included the path to the library of the wxwidgets in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. I have also tried the linking options present in the configure script (--with-wx-prefix). This is the error that I get

```
    root@caos-intel3:~/installationfolders/wxpropertygrid/propgrid

    ./configure --prefix=/root/installedsoftware/wxpropgrid 
    --with-wx-prefix=/root/installedsoftware/wxwidgets/


    checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    checking for the --enable-debug option... will be automatically detected
    checking for the --enable-unicode option... will be automatically detected
    checking for the --enable-shared option... will be automatically detected
    checking for the --with-toolkit option... will be automatically detected
    checking for the --with-wxshared option... will be automatically detected
    checking for the --with-wxversion option... will be automatically detected
    checking for gcc... gcc
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of executables... 
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
    checking for gcc option to accept ANSI C... none needed
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking for wx-config... /root/installedsoftware/wxwidgets//bin/wx-config
    checking for wxWidgets version >= 2.6.1... yes (version 3.0.2)
    checking for wxWidgets static library... no
    checking if wxWidgets was built with UNICODE enabled... yes
    checking if wxWidgets was built in DEBUG mode... no
    checking if wxWidgets was built in STATIC mode... no
    checking which wxWidgets toolkit was selected... configure: error:
    Cannot detect the currently installed wxWidgets port !
    Please check your 'wx-config --cxxflags'...
```

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets 3.0.2, that you use, already includes `wxPropertyGrid` and related classes, you don't have to install anything extra.